# Get value of table and insert into database using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter. I have created one table and its html is like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <center><label style="font-weight:normal" class="t_date"><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></label></center>
     </td>
     <td>
        <center><label style="font-weight:normal" class="b_id"><?php echo $result[0]->branch_id; ?></label></center>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="button" onClick="window.print();" value="Print" name="print" id="print"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to get the value of td so I have written jQuery like this:

```
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#print").click(function(){
                    //alert(123);

                    var to_date = jQuery(".t_date").text();
                    var to_date = jQuery(".b_id").text();

                    });
                });
        </script>
```

And I got value of it. Now i want to insert these all value into database so what code should i have to write?

Comment: Store that value in hidden & submit form.

Comment: you can submit the data in next page using post in jquery and save it to the database on next page.

Comment: @priya786 so you said using ajax right?

Comment: yes there you can use it also like $.post('yourpagename','values1:value1',function(){}) like this in vlaue you can send variables ok

Comment: @priya786 Ohk thanks. Let me try.

Comment: if you want detail answer then tell me i will do

Comment: @priya786 i have used ajax and its working. Thanks for your suggesion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81635/discussion-between-nisarg-and-priya786).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#print").click(function () {
            alert(123);
            var to_date = jQuery(".t_date").text();
            var to_id = jQuery(".b_id").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/function",
                data: {to_date: to_date, to_id: to_id},
                success: function (html) //we're calling the response json array 'permissions'
                {
                    // action
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

this ajax will call your function in controller.. in your function call a model function to insert the values to db.

Answer (score 0):

> Refer - [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#print").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
            dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
            data: {
                t_date: jQuery(".t_date").text(),
                b_id: jQuery(".b_id").text(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```

this will do the work

Answer (score 0):

you can do so using AJAX.

Create a webpage to accept inputs as parameters and save them into database.
And study this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

code to do so:

```
$.get("web page address with parameters ", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

For example: if you created a webpage named "savedata.php" that takes inputs as parameters and saves into database.

Then

```
 $.get("[root_path]/savedata.php?[paramaters]", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

[root_path] is the root path of you webpage and [parameters] is "&" separated parameters.